# Java Дженерики. Растолкуйте объявление

Tags: java, generics

Java Дженерики. Растолкуйте объявление для чайников, сигнатуру объявления
что делает ? super T
читаю, не особо могу вникнуть

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list) {...}
```

```
public class MergeSort {

public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list) {...}


}~~~
```

Answer (score 4):

? - это как generic T, но вы его не сможете использовать в качестве класса, знак вопроса говорит о том что не важно какой это будет класс, это необходимо как раз для конструкций с применением extends и super в дженериках.

> ? extends T - означает, что любой, указанный в generic, класс ? обязан
>   быть **наследником** T

В то же время

> ? super T - означает, что любой, указанный в generic, класс ? обязан
>   быть **родителем** T

Пример:

```
public class Animal {
  int age; 
}

public class Cat extends Animal implements Comparable<Animal> {
    @Override public int compareTo(Animal that) {
        // компаратор для сравнения кошек с другими животными
    }
}

public class Dog extends Animal implements Comparable<Animal> {
    @Override public int compareTo(Animal that) {
        // компаратор для сравнения собак с другими животными
    }
}
```

---

```
class ByAgeAsc implements Comparator<Animal> { //общий компаратор для животных по возрасту
    @Override public int compare(Animal a, Animal b) {
        return a.getAge() < b.getAge();
    }
}

List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<>();
animals.add(new Cat(5)); // коту 5 лет
animals.add(new Dog(10)); //собаке 10 лет
Collections.sort(students, new ByAgeAsc()); //сортируем по возрасту
```

По сути объявление `generic` в `sort` можно прочитать как:

Метод сортировки использует определяемый позднее класс `T`, который должен быть наследником класса или реализовывать интерфейс `Comparable`, в котором объявленный позднее класс `?` (неиспользуемый в дальнейшем коде) будет классом родителем или интерфейсом класса `T`.